# Правильно ли я интерпретирую результаты профилирования NodeJS-приложения?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаюсь профилировать бэкенд на Ноде (Express.JS). Тестирую под нагрузкой ApacheBench (10000 запросов с конкурентностью 500 запросов в секунду). Простенькая страничка - сходи в кэш за одними данными, потом за другими, потом сгенери страничку и выдай клиенту. С 10,000 запросов бэкенд справляется за 7 секунд.

Встроенный профилировщик V8 выдаёт такое:

```
 [Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
    202    4.3%   92.7%  JavaScript
      0    0.0%    0.0%  C++
    324    7.0%  148.6%  GC
   4442   95.3%          Shared libraries
     16    0.3%          Unaccounted
```

Т.е. мой код и сборщик мусора вместе занимают 11% от общего числа тиков. Всё остальное - Shared Libraries. Иду туда, а там:

```
 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   3566   76.5%          /usr/bin/node
    407    8.7%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
    382    8.2%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
     72    1.5%          [vdso]
     13    0.3%          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
      2    0.0%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
```

Значит ли это, что я оптимизировал свой код по максимуму и упёрся в производительность самой Ноды?